# Analytical solution to non-linear 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

Is there an analytical solution to the following non-linear ODE?

$$y''(x) = A \frac{y}{B+\alpha y} ... (1)$$ where $A,B,\alpha$ are constants.

The boundary conditions are:

$$y'(x = 0) = y'(x = L) = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that $A = B = \alpha = 1$ for the sake of simplicity.

Then we can multiply both sides by $y'$, whence we get

\begin{align*}
y'' = \frac{y}{1 + y} & \Rightarrow y''y' = \left(\frac{y}{1+y}\right)y' = \left(1 - \frac{1}{1+y}\right)y'
\end{align*}

Then we can integrate both sides in order to obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{(y')^{2}}{2} = y - \ln|1 + y| + c
\end{align*}

which is not solvable in terms of elementary functions.

Similar procedure can be applied to the general case.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: So does this mean that this equation has no analytical solution?

Comment: I am afraid so.

Comment: How do you conclude there's no closed form? Just because it looks very challenging?

Comment: I usually check with WA, which has not given an answer to this expression (at least for the free version). But maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

$y(x)=0$ is a solution to the problem.